# interesting sql query with random

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with 1000 rows with the following pattern

```
id d1  date                        Type
   1  N   2012-03-09 00:00:00.000     C
   2  No  2011-09-26 00:00:00.000     C
   3  N   2012-01-26 00:00:00.000     R
   4  N   2012-03-07 00:00:00.000     R
   5  yes 2012-02-23 00:00:00.000     C
   6  N   2012-03-09 00:00:00.000     C
   7  No  2011-09-26 00:00:00.000     C
   8  N   2012-01-26 00:00:00.000     R
   9  N   2012-03-07 00:00:00.000     R
   10  yes 2012-02-23 00:00:00.000     C
```

I want out put like below

```
id d1  date                        Type
   1  N   2012-03-09 00:00:00.000     C
   3  No  2011-09-26 00:00:00.000     R
   2  N   2012-01-26 00:00:00.000     C
   4  N   2012-03-07 00:00:00.000     R
   5  yes 2012-02-23 00:00:00.000     C
   8  N   2012-03-09 00:00:00.000     R
   7  No  2011-09-26 00:00:00.000     C
   9  N   2012-01-26 00:00:00.000     R
   6  N   2012-03-07 00:00:00.000     c
   10  yes 2012-02-23 00:00:00.000     R
```

i need to show 10 random rows and that order should be based on the TYPE field. and the TYPE FIELD should be like

```
c
r
c
r
c
r
```

pattern.

Comment: Do you want a random sample of your data or the whole set, just in a random order every time you query it?

Comment: i want random but type like c r c r....

Comment: sorry, can't make out what the ... you want ...

Comment: Are the values in the table rows given or do you want to generate random values? It would be nice, if you could post your question in a reasonably understandable fashion.

Comment: i want pick up random rows and type should be C R c R ...

Comment: So you have a large number of bits and you want to sweep a bunch into a bag and toss in, at random, a "c", a "C" or an "R", then toss the bag on a pile.  Then you want to take the bags from the pile and line them up so that the letters alternate between a "C" in either uppercase or lowercase and an "R".  If you have an overabundance of some letter then you're content to shove the remaining bags into a bit bucket.  Does that explain it?

Comment: I have large number of bits and here not bother about case either upper or lower case .If i run query i want take 20 rows apart from 100 rows but the type should be a 'C',an 'R',a 'c', an 'R'....so on up to 20 rows.

Comment: We need to cross this language barrier before somebody set up us the bomb.  You mean the type should alternate between values "C" and "R"?

Comment: Type should alternate row values "C" and "R", plz see my post out put data type row

Comment: Honestly, your description is really hard to work with. I've tried to match something close to what you want, but like BalamBalam said, your sample doesn't alternate entirely and I'll add that it isn't sorted on Id and won't alternate when it is. I don't know what it *is* ordered by. I updated my answer to give the final result set alternating 'R' and 'C' records. Is that closer?

Comment: i cannot copy 1000 records here just i wrote 10 sample data in that only i ordered with type column

Comment: There is no order that alternates values that I know of. You picked an arbitrary order that the db isn't going to be able to do. You have to have another column that is sequential to sort on as far as I know, which is why am putting things in the final table on a random order, having the type alternate based on id and allowing it to be sorted by id. If you would perhaps comment on any of the answers with why they don't meet your needs perhaps we could tailor our answers better. I'll fix mine if you tell me why it doesn't work.

Comment: i am using sql2000 that is my problem,and i do not want random values i need random rows

Comment: The values in the example I gave you are not random, the order is. I'm using RAND() to randomize the order. You also said sql 2005 in your original post. Does my answer not work on that? Did you try it?

Comment: @JeremyPridemore Why are you still trying to help this guy?

Comment: @Sree Your sample output list is NOT random. The sample output is all from the first 10.

Comment: @BalamBalam Eh, because I spent too much time on the original answer and if he would have just given some clear direction it could have been right. *shrugs*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
SELECT t.id
       ,t.d1
       ,t.[date]
       ,t.[Type]
  FROM
    (
    -- Get 10 random rows
    SELECT TOP 10 id
           ,d1
           ,[date]
           ,[Type]
      FROM [table]
     ORDER BY NEWID() -- use NewID() to randomize result set
    ) t
     ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.[Type] ORDER BY t.id) ASC
     ,t.[Type] ASC
```

Answer (score 4):

I solved this using some RAND() calls. I tried to make computed columns, but the inserts were all getting the same value. The value was random from call to call, but the same within the query. Inserting a different call to RAND() each time got around that, but I had to repeat the case logic for each value, which wasn't quite ideal. Here is how I solved this:

```
DECLARE @RandomizedTypes TABLE
(
    TempId FLOAT
    , d1 VARCHAR(3)
    , [Date] DATETIME
)

INSERT @RandomizedTypes
(
    TempId
    , d1
    , [Date]
)
VALUES
    (RAND(), 'N', '2012-03-09 00:00:00.000')
    , (RAND(), 'No', '2011-09-26 00:00:00.000')
    , (RAND(), 'N', '2012-01-26 00:00:00.000')
    , (RAND(), 'N', '2012-03-07 00:00:00.000')
    , (RAND(), 'yes', '2012-02-23 00:00:00.000')
    , (RAND(), 'N', '2012-03-09 00:00:00.000')
    , (RAND(), 'No', '2011-09-26 00:00:00.000')
    , (RAND(), 'N', '2012-01-26 00:00:00.000')
    , (RAND(), 'N', '2012-03-07 00:00:00.000')
    , (RAND(), 'yes', '2012-02-23 00:00:00.000')

DECLARE @FinalRandomizedTable TABLE
(
    id INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
    , d1 VARCHAR(3)
    , [Date] DATETIME
    , [Type] AS CASE WHEN (id % 2) = 0 THEN 'R' ELSE 'C' END
)

INSERT @FinalRandomizedTable
(
    d1
    , [Date]
)
SELECT
    d1
    , [Date]
FROM @RandomizedTypes
ORDER BY TempId

SELECT * FROM @FinalRandomizedTable
```

EDIT: Modified to alternate 'R' and 'C' Rows as per the updated question.

Comment: Don't use table variable, use #Temp tables instead.

Comment: Sometimes one is appropriate, sometimes the other. I see no useful value out of using a temp table for a result so small and was mostly just giving an idea of how to implement the logic. The logic is the same with a temp table and you can index it if you want and all that.

If there is a good reason to not use a table variable even with a record set of 10, I'd love to learn what that is.

Comment: I ran on this question, and I just wanted to point out. Yes, you are right if you have up to few hundred rows, it's ok to use table variable, but from my experience, and from many others, if you have thousands or maybe millions of rows, you'll have problem, because table variables are not treated same way by the memory as temp tables. And if you create table with # you don't have to drop it in stored procedure, it will be automatically droped when session ends.

Comment: @el ninho And yet there are cases where #temp tables actually handle this better (please see http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13392/why-is-using-a-table-variable-more-than-twice-as-fast-as-a-temp-table-in-this-s). I think it's very inappropriate to say "always use table variables" or "never use table variables." There is no blanket answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's what you want.

```
SELECT id,d1,date,Type
FROM (
select ((RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY randomRank)) * 2 + 1) rank, id,d1,date,Type
FROM (SELECT top 10 NEWID() randomRank,id,d1,date,Type FROM YourTable  WHERE Type = 'C' ORDER BY NEWID()) a
UNION 
select ((RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY randomRank)) * 2 ) rank, id,d1,date,Type
FROM (SELECT top 10 NEWID() randomRank,id,d1,date,Type FROM YourTable  WHERE Type = 'R' ORDER BY NEWID()) a
)b order by rank
```

Answer (score -2):

```
;with abcd
as
(
    select id, d1, date, types,
           ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by types order by types asc) as number 
    from sampledata 
)

select * from abcd order by number,types
```